# python sliding window average for letters

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file like this:

```
chr1 1 A 3
chr1 2 G 3
chr1 3 T 3
chr1 4 C 2
chr1 5 G 1
chr1 6 T 2
chr1 7 G 3
chr1 8 C 3
chr1 9 A 5
chr1 10 A 8
chr2 5 A 1
chr2 6 G 0
chr2 7 G 0
chr2 8 G 0
chr2 9 C 2
chr2 10 T 3
chr2 11 A 3
```

What I would like to do is:
setting a window size (let's say 2), move with it along the file, and compute average of column 4 and % of G+C inside the window.

I have sth like this for now:

```
import numpy
def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
    window = numpy.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
    return numpy.convolve(interval, window, 'same')
```

it does the work for 4th column, but I don't know how to apply this to calculate content of G+C inside the window frame

Cheers,
Irek

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean if the content is G+A, the % is 50%?  And if it is G+C, it is 100%?

Comment: yep. in simples form: content of the G+C inside the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import tee, izip
from collections import Counter

text = '''\
chr1 1 A 3
chr1 2 G 3
chr1 3 T 3
chr1 4 C 2
chr1 5 G 1
chr1 6 T 2
chr1 7 G 3
chr1 8 C 3
chr1 9 A 5
chr1 10 A 8
chr2 5 A 1
chr2 6 G 0
chr2 7 G 0
chr2 8 G 0
chr2 9 C 2
chr2 10 T 3
chr2 11 A 3'''


def window(iterable, size):
    iters = tee(iterable, size)
    for i in xrange(1, size):
        for each in iters[i:]:
            next(each, None)
    return izip(*iters)


def get_avg(lists, column):
    return sum(zip(*lists)[column]) / len(lists)


def get_GC_percentage(lists, column):
    counts = Counter(zip(*lists)[column])
    return (counts['C'] + counts['G']) / len(lists)


line_tuples = (line.split() for line in text.split('\n'))
line_tuples_casted = ((a,int(b),c,int(d)) for a,b,c,d in line_tuples)
line_tuples_chunks = window(line_tuples_casted, 2)

for (i,chunk) in enumerate(line_tuples_chunks):
    print 'i: {:2} | avg: {} | GC_content: {:5.0%}'.format(i, get_avg(chunk, 3), get_GC_percentage(chunk, 2))
```

Output:

```
i:  0 | avg: 3.0 | GC_content:   50%
i:  1 | avg: 3.0 | GC_content:   50%
i:  2 | avg: 2.5 | GC_content:   50%
i:  3 | avg: 1.5 | GC_content:  100%
i:  4 | avg: 1.5 | GC_content:   50%
i:  5 | avg: 2.5 | GC_content:   50%
i:  6 | avg: 3.0 | GC_content:  100%
i:  7 | avg: 4.0 | GC_content:   50%
i:  8 | avg: 6.5 | GC_content:    0%
i:  9 | avg: 4.5 | GC_content:    0%
i: 10 | avg: 0.5 | GC_content:   50%
i: 11 | avg: 0.0 | GC_content:  100%
i: 12 | avg: 0.0 | GC_content:  100%
i: 13 | avg: 1.0 | GC_content:  100%
i: 14 | avg: 2.5 | GC_content:   50%
i: 15 | avg: 3.0 | GC_content:    0%
```

But note, this is not quite optimal solution. We could do better by not calculating average on each iteration for the whole window, but update it using the values which leave the window and come to it.

Comment: hmm where exactly can I scale the window size? I assume that line_tuples_chunks ? Or do i also have change the value somewhere else?

Comment: @lerk Yeah, window size is set at `line_tuples_chunks = window(line_tuples_casted, 2)`. It is the only place the window size is determined. It is a good coding style to define the same functionality only once.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood what you want to do, here is one way (not optimal but works):

First data file **file.data**

```
chr1 1 A 3
chr1 2 G 3
chr1 3 T 3
chr1 4 C 2
chr1 5 G 1
chr1 6 T 2
chr1 7 G 3
chr1 8 C 3
chr1 9 A 5
chr1 10 A 8
chr2 5 A 1
chr2 6 G 0
chr2 7 G 0
chr2 8 G 0
chr2 9 C 2
chr2 10 T 3
chr2 11 A 3
```

Now the script:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'A':0, 'G': 1, 'T':2, 'C':3, 'U':4}
data = np.loadtxt('file.data', delimiter=' ', converters = {0: lambda x: int(x[-1]), 2: lambda x: d[x]})
win_size = 2

for i in range(data.shape[0] / win_size):
    m = data[i:i+win_size,:]
    avg = np.mean(m[:,3])
    cg_per = float(np.where( ( m[:,2] == d['G'] )| ( m[:,2] == d['C']) )[0].shape[0]) * 100 / win_size

    print "Window {0} avg:{1} C+G={2}%".format(i, avg, cg_per)
```

It will generate:

```
Window 0 avg:3.0 C+G=50.0%
Window 1 avg:3.0 C+G=50.0%
Window 2 avg:2.5 C+G=50.0%
Window 3 avg:1.5 C+G=100.0%
Window 4 avg:1.5 C+G=50.0%
Window 5 avg:2.5 C+G=50.0%
Window 6 avg:3.0 C+G=100.0%
Window 7 avg:4.0 C+G=50.0%
```

Comment: ahh I forgot to mention that's a huge file. dictionary will kill my memory, not to mention index is easily out of range

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already know how to get your data into a numpy array, so lets say you have them in an array named `bases`. If you now do:

```
base_mask = (bases == 'G') | (basses == 'C')
```

You have a boolean mask with `True` wherever the array has a G or a C, and `False` elsewhere. Since booleans casted to ints have the `True`s converted to `1`s and the `False`s to `0`s, simply compute the average on the `base_mask` array the same way you are doing for `interval`.

Comment: yep, I thought of it, even in simpler form, simply changing all C,G to 1, other to 0 without intermediate false/true (don't know if ommiting boolean would make it quicker)

Answer (score 1):

Deques are great for sliding windows. Try the following:

```python
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

FN = "temp.txt"
WSIZE = 2

def gen_stream(f):
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        yield [1 if line[2] in 'GC' else 0, int(line[3])]

def overlapping():
    with open(FN) as f:
        stream = gen_stream(f)
        window = deque([stream.next() for _ in xrange(WSIZE-1)], WSIZE)
        for row in stream:
            window.append(row)
            print [sum(row[i] for row in window)/float(WSIZE) for i in xrange(2)]

def non_overlapping():
    with open(FN) as f:
        stream = gen_stream(f)
        while True:
            chunk = list(islice(stream, WSIZE))
            if not chunk:
                break
            print [sum(row[i] for row in chunk)/float(len(chunk)) for i in xrange(2)]
```

This is scalable, i.e., works for a huge file.

Comment: cool, great solution. I will look if there aren't any unusal things. This is no overlapping window, right?

Comment: I tried to change the window size, and swittched WSIZE only, but I have a feeling, that it isn't enough?

Comment: My initial solution was meant for overlapping windows. I just edited the original answer to include a solution for non-overlapping ones. In the latter case, using a deque would bring little advantage

Comment: `overlapping` seems to raise `StopIteration` for example when `WSIZE=3` and `stream` has only one value in it.